# How to make a circle grow depending on how long the user holds (Java Script)

Tags: javascript, html

ok here is the deal, I want a circle to grow on a canvas depending on how long you hold your mouse button. I was able to make it draw a circle of fixed width where my mouse was when I clicked, but I want to be able to determine size based on how long I hold. Ideally, you will be able to see it grow as you hold.

CODE

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

document.addEventListener("mousedown", draw);
document.addEventListener("mousedown", time1);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", time2);

//Size
function time1(event) {
    var a = new Date().getTime() + 1;
    return a;
}

function time2(event) {
    var b = new Date().getTime() + 4;
    return b;
}
var c ="Time: " + (time2 - time1);
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = c;

function draw(event, a , b) {
    //Cords
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;

    //Fill
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0c67f9";
    //Draw
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x ,y ,(b - a),0,Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();
}    

function showCoords(event) {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coords;
}

/*function grow(event) {
    var z = event.time;
}*/
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="690" height="651" onclick="showCoords(event)" style ="border: 1px solid #e21313"></canvas>    
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="time"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your groing circle:
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Aaron3219/ajrw5ko0/35/)

But I don't want to give you the copy & paste solution.
So with my help I believe you can figure it out.

First of all you need to change the event listener so it doesn't get triggered if you hold down your mouse somewhere in the `html` area (like it is now). Set it from `$("html")` to `$("#your-canvas")`.
Since you also don't want to see your circle the whole time and it can't have a static position you also want to change the CSS attributes of the `.dot` class. I believe `display: none;` and `position: absolute;` will do.
The last thing you want to do is to get the exact mouse position (with `offset` and everything) and set it as CSS attributes `top` and `left` (don't forget to set the `display: none` to `display: block`).
Boom you got your growing circle.

However I didn't really understand what you mean by:

> but I want to be able to determine size based on how long I hold.